# Sum rows of data (filtered on a condition) for a range of days using offset, index and match formula in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, offset

Hi I am trying to come up with a sum that will filter over a condition ("A") and add all the dates in the range (example 6/1/19 - 6/12/19). Using offset, match, and index I get an output that is much higher than than the expected result. Not sure where I am going wrong with this. Attaching a screenshot of the formula, data and the output. Below is the data pasted as text.

Screenshot of the data and current formula

[image]

**Here is the current formula:**

```
=SUM(OFFSET($B$3,MATCH("A",$B$3:$B$17,0),MATCH($D$1,$B$3:$N$3,0),COUNTIF($B$3:$B$17,"A"),MATCH($D$2,$C$3:$N$3,0)-MATCH($D$1,$C$3:$N$3,0)))
```

**Here is the data:**

```
| Type | 6/1/2019 | 6/2/2019 | 6/3/2019 | 6/4/2019 | 6/5/2019 | 6/6/2019 | 6/7/2019 | 6/8/2019 | 6/9/2019 | 6/10/2019 | 6/11/2019 | 6/12/2019 |
|------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| A    | 983      | 950      | 1222     | 1329     | 1254     | 1176     | 1120     | 1018     | 974      | 931       | 989       | 925       |
| A    | 454      | 483      | 412      | 376      | 366      | 366      | 338      | 414      | 456      | 369       | 390       | 380       |
| A    | 308      | 361      | 337      | 377      | 361      | 340      | 323      | 361      | 383      | 385       | 350       | 305       |
| B    | 196      | 190      | 198      | 212      | 173      | 180      | 181      | 185      | 179      | 173       | 21969     | 16945     |
| C    | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0         | 0         | 0         |
| B    | 191      | 250      | 244      | 222      | 197      | 172      | 181      | 155      | 184      | 184       | 168       | 147       |
| C    | 211      | 233      | 158      | 142      | 128      | 139      | 164      | 189      | 214      | 225       | 162       | 139       |
| D    | 370      | 403      | 420      | 833      | 1177     | 632      | 432      | 419      | 467      | 438       | 397       | 365       |
| A    | 202      | 244      | 230      | 263      | 215      | 193      | 178      | 231      | 754      | 514       | 246       | 251       |
| B    | 229      | 242      | 261      | 281      | 253      | 251      | 235      | 246      | 307      | 274       | 224       | 216       |
| C    | 262      | 261      | 259      | 212      | 209      | 205      | 211      | 238      | 273      | 223       | 222       | 241       |
| A    | 370      | 403      | 420      | 833      | 1177     | 632      | 432      | 419      | 467      | 438       | 397       | 365       |
| D    | 262      | 261      | 259      | 212      | 209      | 205      | 211      | 238      | 273      | 223       | 222       | 241       |
| D    | 370      | 403      | 420      | 833      | 1177     | 632      | 432      | 419      | 467      | 438       | 397       | 365       |
```

Comment: What are we supposed to do with your screenshot? It is virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. Having to manually enter the data is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables),

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thank you for your comment. I have edited my question to include data as text. The formatting is not at it's the best. Thanks!

Comment: I can help with the formula formatting.  But please use the link to the Markdown Tables Generator in my comment above so that the data can be properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

For a formula approach, I suggest:

```
=SUM(INDEX($C$4:$N$17,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($B$4:$B$17=C22)*ROW($B$4:$B$17)-3,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNTIF($B$4:$B$17,C22)))),COLUMN(INDEX($1:$1,1):INDEX($1:$1,COUNTA($C$3:$N$3)))))
```

where `C22` contains the Type you wish to filter on

If you have Excel O365 with the Filter function, you can use:

```
=SUM(FILTER($C$4:$N$17,$B$4:$B$17=C21))
```

Or you could use a Pivot Table or Power Query

Answer (score 0):

See https://exceljet.net/formula/sum-matching-columns-and-rows

Your implementation would be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C4:N17*(B4:B17=E1)*(C3:N3>=D1)*(C3:N3<=D2))
```